# How to Create Collapsible Data Grid?

Tags: .net, winforms, gridview, datagridview, collapsable

How to Create Collapsible Data Grid in dot net windows form application?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there are no default controls that would support this. You'll need a 3rd party control library. I recommend [Devexpress](http://www.devexpress.com/)

Answer (score -1):

I don't know of a specific API method, but you can use Javascript to make it collapsing, or simply a postback in which you only set the visibility.

Comment: I want teh solution in windows form.